# Select MYSQL rows but rows into columns and column into rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select all the rows in my database but I want them in inverted sequence. Meaning, I want to use the first column data as the new entities and present entities as the first column. I think you got what I mean

Here is an illustration

```
id    |     name       | marks
-------------------------------
1     |    Ram         | 45
--------------------------------
2     |    Shyam       |  87
```

to

```
id    |   1     |    2     |
----------------------------
Name  |  Ram    |   Shyam  |
----------------------------
Marks |  45     |    87    |
```

Comment: You need the inverted sequence in PHP ? In SQL it would have no meaning I guess...

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns - but can you explain WHY you want this? There probably is a better solution.

Comment: @kaavier, I know how to do it in PHP? But I need a sql solution

Comment: This probably can't be done in mySQL. It's not what it was designed for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With a fixed and known columns, here's how to do it (I took the liberty of naming the table "grades"):

### General Idea:

To create a union of different queries and execute it.

Since you need actual data as column headers, the first part of the union will look like:

```
SELECT 'id', '1', '2', ....
```

That query alone will duplicate the result, therefore we need to tell MySQL we need to have 0 rows by adding `LIMIT 0, 0`.

Our first row of the union will contain `'Name'`, as well as all the data from "Name" column of the table. To get that line we need a query like:

```
SELECT 'Name',
    (SELECT Name FROM grades LIMIT 0, 1),
    (SELECT Name FROM grades LIMIT 1, 1),
    (SELECT Name FROM grades LIMIT 2, 1),
    ...
```

Using the same logic, our second row will look like:

```
SELECT 'Marks',
    (SELECT Marks FROM grades LIMIT 0, 1),
    (SELECT Marks FROM grades LIMIT 1, 1),
    (SELECT Marks FROM grades LIMIT 2, 1),
    ...
```

### Getting the header:

We need to produce a row from MySQL like:

```
SELECT 'id', '1', '2', ... LIMIT 0, 0;
```

To get that line we will use [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) functions:

```
SELECT 'id', 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' \'', id, '\'')) FROM grades)
LIMIT 0, 0;
```

and we're going to store that line into a new variable:

```
SET @header = CONCAT('SELECT \'id\', ',
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' \'', id, '\'')) FROM grades),
    ' LIMIT 0, 0');
```

### Creating the lines:

We need to create two queries like the following:

```
SELECT 'Name',
    (SELECT Name FROM grades LIMIT 0, 1),
    (SELECT Name FROM grades LIMIT 1, 1),
    (SELECT Name FROM grades LIMIT 2, 1),
    ...
```

Since we do not know in advance how many rows there are in our original table, we will be using variables to generate the different `LIMIT x, 1` statements. They can be produced using the following:

```
SET @a = -1;
SELECT @a:=@a+1 FROM grades;
```

Using this snippet, we can create our subqueries:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(' (SELECT name FROM grades LIMIT ',
        @a:=@a+1,
        ', 1)')
    )
FROM grades
```

Which we will put into a variable names @line1, along with the first column data (which is the second column's name):

```
SET @a = -1;
SET @line1 = CONCAT(
    'SELECT \'Name\',',
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(' (SELECT Name FROM grades LIMIT ',
                @a:=@a+1,
                ', 1)')
            )
        FROM grades
    ));
```

By following the same logic, the second line will be:

```
SET @a := -1;
SET @line2 = CONCAT(
    'SELECT \'Marks\',',
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(' (SELECT Marks FROM grades LIMIT ',
                @a:=@a+1,
                ', 1)')
            )
        FROM grades
    ));
```

### Combining them all:

Our three variables now contain:

```
@header:
SELECT 'id',  '1', '2' LIMIT 0, 0

@line1:
SELECT 'Name', (SELECT Name FROM grades LIMIT 0, 1),
    (SELECT name FROM grades LIMIT 1, 1)

@line2:
SELECT 'Marks', (SELECT Marks FROM grades LIMIT 0, 1),
    (SELECT marks FROM grades LIMIT 1, 1)
```

We just need to create a final variable using `CONCAT()`, prepare it as a new query and execute it:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('(',
    @header,
    ') UNION (',
    @line1,
    ') UNION (',
    @line2,
    ')'
);

PREPARE my_query FROM @query;
EXECUTE my_query;
```

### Entire solution:

(for testing and reference):

```
SET @header = CONCAT('SELECT \'id\', ',
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' \'', id, '\'')) FROM grades),
    ' LIMIT 0, 0');

SET @a = -1;
SET @line1 = CONCAT(
    'SELECT \'Name\',',
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(' (SELECT Name FROM grades LIMIT ',
                @a:=@a+1,
                ', 1)')
            )
        FROM grades
    ));

SET @a := -1;
SET @line2 = CONCAT(
    'SELECT \'Marks\',',
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(' (SELECT Marks FROM grades LIMIT ',
                @a:=@a+1,
                ', 1)')
            )
        FROM grades
    ));

SET @query = CONCAT('(',
    @header,
    ') UNION (',
    @line1,
    ') UNION (',
    @line2,
    ')'
);

PREPARE my_query FROM @query;
EXECUTE my_query;
```

Output:

```
+-------+------+-------+
| id    | 1    | 2     |
+-------+------+-------+
| Name  | Ram  | Shyam |
| Marks | 45   | 87    |
+-------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Closing thoughts:

- I'm still not sure why you need to transform rows into columns, and I'm sure the solution I presented is not the best one (in terms of performance).
- You can even use my solution as a start and adapt it to a general purpose solution where the table column names (and the number of lines) are not known, using `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` as a source, but I guess that's just going too far.
- I strongly believe it is much better to put the original table into an array and then rotate that array, thus getting the data in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're looking for is a crosstab (or transpose) operation on your data.

Here's an excellent article describing how to accomplish this: http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2003/12/04/crosstabs.html - it's a bit dated though, not sure if by now there are more efficient ways to go about doing this. It works well enough for me.

Answer (score -1):

On command line you can end your query with \G to achieve this
e.g.

```
select * from `students`\G;
```

Comment: interesting. but i don't think this is what the op is looking for. it will show each row as a block, and not every row side by side

Comment: agreed. And I'm not sure if this would even work with php's mysql functions, but this is the closest thing I know of :)