# SELECT something JOIN ON something IN columns of multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to integrate a bunch of SELECTs all into one.

I have multiple tables that look similar to the following:

**Table: A1**

```
+---+----+----+----+----+
|id | I1 | I2 | I3 | I4 |
+---+----+----+----+----+
| 1 |  5 |  6 |  1 |  3 |
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

**Table: A2**

```
+---+----+----+----+
|id | I1 | I2 | I3 |
+---+----+----+----+
| 1 |  3 | 10 |  5 |
+---+----+----+----+
```

And 1 table that looks like this:

**Table: Standards**

```
+---+---------+
|id |   Name  | 
+---+---------+
| 1 | 'one'   |
| 2 | 'two'   | 
| 3 | 'three' |
| 4 | 'four'  | 
| 5 | 'five'  | 
| 6 | 'six'   |
| 7 | 'seven' |
| 8 | 'eight' |
| 9 | 'nine'  | 
|10 | 'ten'   |
+---+---------+
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    while(/*"A" tables*/){
        $noi = // number of columns in this A table
        $id = // id of this A table
        $columns = "";
        for ($i=1; $i<=$noi; $i++){
            $columns = $columns . "A" . $id . ".I" . $i . ", ";
        }
        $columns = rtrim($columns, ", ");

        $sql = "SELECT s.* FROM A" . $id . "
            INNER JOIN Standards AS s
            ON s.id IN (" . $columns . ") 
            WHERE A" . $id . ".id=1
            ORDER BY s.id ASC";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
?>
```

I'd like to combine all of these SELECTS into 1.  I was thinking I could run a for loop to generate all the names of the tables, but I wasn't sure exactly how to join them with the other JOIN ON ... IN (...) that's in there.

The results I want to generate are:

```
+---+---------+
|id |   Name  | 
+---+---------+
| 1 | 'one'   |
| 3 | 'three' | 
| 5 | 'five'  | 
| 6 | 'six'   |
|10 | 'ten'   |
+---+---------+
```

Comment: This would be easier if you could pivot the table (ie: turn columns into rows). AFAIK MySQL doesn't have this capability.

Comment: The problem with that is that there are hundreds of rows after id #1 in the A tables.

Comment: I am curious though; why are the tables structured like this? When this kind of problem appears, it could be a sign of bad db design.

Comment: I'll be the first to admit that it's bad DB design.  The tables each represent a multiple choice test that each have different numbers of test items (the columns).  The rows are each new administration of that test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this solution, it should give you a foundation of how to do this:

[select-mysql-rows-but-rows-into-columns-and-column-into-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288014/select-mysql-rows-but-rows-into-columns-and-column-into-rows)

In short, you might want to try to select the values from each row's columns as rows from the 2 tables and UNION those datasets, then JOIN them onto the lookup table. The result should be what you described. (I am assuming that all of the I1, I2, I3, etc. columns represent IDs in your lookup table)

Comment: I think UNION is going to work for me.  Without me trying it out myself, does anyone know if you can do an ORDER BY on a UNION?

Comment: Sure, like this: `SELECT field1
FROM ( SELECT field1 FROM table1
       UNION
       SELECT field1 FROM table2
     )
ORDER BY field1`

Comment: Can refer to this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213851/sql-query-using-order-by-in-union

Comment: SQL is truly amazing.  Thanks for your help!