# How to dynamically turn rows into columns and vice versa

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, dynamic-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select MYSQL rows but rows into columns and column into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288014/select-mysql-rows-but-rows-into-columns-and-column-into-rows)

How to display from:

```
╔══════╦════╦════╗
║ Code ║ A  ║ B  ║
╠══════╬════╬════╣
║ xxxx ║ 50 ║ 63 ║
║ yyyy ║ 38 ║ 68 ║
║ .... ║ .. ║ .. ║
╚══════╩════╩════╝
```

to like this:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦═════╗
║ Code ║ xxxx ║ yyyy ║ ... ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬═════╣
║ A    ║   50 ║   63 ║ ... ║
║ B    ║   38 ║   68 ║ ... ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩═════╝
```

As it may have a few "code" like xxxx, yyyy, zzzz, ...
So, I need to display all the "code" in dynamically without hard-coded.

Comment: There is no standard way to achieve this dynamically just using regular sql

Comment: btw, i need to get the header without hardcoded. is that possible?

Comment: Have a look at these links - [Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html), [Automate pivot table queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#523).

Comment: What happens if there are multiple records with the same `Code`?

Comment: Hope there is an index to group data.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have an `UNPIVOT` or a `PIVOT` function but they can be replicated using a `UNION ALL` for `UNPIVOT` and an aggregate function with `CASE` statement for the `PIVOT`.  If you know the values that you want to transform, then you can hard-code then similar to the following:

```
select col code,
  sum(case when code = 'xxxx' then value end) xxxx,
  sum(case when code = 'xxxx' then value end) yyyy
from
(
  select code, A value, 'A' col
  from table1
  union all
  select code, B value, 'B' col
  from table1
) x
group by col;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0990/1)

But you stated that you will have an unknown number of `code` values. If that is the case then you can use a prepared statement to `pivot` the data:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when code = ''',
      code,
      ''' then value end) AS ',
      code
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT col as code, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM
                  (
                    select code, A value, ''A'' col
                    from table1
                    union all
                    select code, B value, ''B'' col
                    from table1
                  ) x
                  GROUP BY col');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abca5/8).

Both produce the same results:

```
| CODE | XXXX | YYYY |
----------------------
|    A |   50 |   38 |
|    B |   63 |   68 |
```

Comment: how about if this question in "toad for oracle"(plsql). what is the solution for it? Thanks a lot to anyone help.

Comment: @Jimmy428 what version of Oracle?  The answer is different depending on the version.