# How to get the minimum value from the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table Item and I want to get the minimum price of the Item for the particular id

**Table Item:**

```
Id    Price1                Price2           Price3
1       10                    20                30
2       20                    30                40
```

According to the above example, the minimum price for **id-1** is **10** and for **id-2** is **20**. I simply just want to get the minimum value from the three column for particular id.

**Remember:** I can't create the cases as, any column can be null. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use case? Just put corresponding conditions like Price1 is not null; Price2 is not null etc

Comment: It's generally a sign of a poor database design if *multiple* columns are storing the same "kind" of data, such that it makes sense to compare their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be like this:

```
SELECT Id, MIN(Price) FROM (
   SELECT Id, Price1 As Price FROM Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Id, Price2 As Price FROM Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Id, Price3 As Price FROM Table1
) As AllValues
GROUP BY Id
```

This works even if there are `null` values. Here is the [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce957/1).

Comment: I am using sql server 2008, is this approach works fine even in sql server 2005?

Comment: @garvitgupta yes it should work without any issues in sql server 2005 too.

Comment: When I run this query, it throws error of Invalid column name id, really strange, don't know why. I am typing the coulmn name exactly correct.

Comment: Here you give the link of working demo, I copied the "Create" statement query and try to build a schema on my local, and again it throw an error of "Incorrect syntax near 'auto_increment", it looks really strange.

Comment: @garvitgupta I have updated that link of working demo, please try again. Update link is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce957/1

Comment: Yes I have done the same updation on my local, now it is working fine.

Comment: Your approach gives me 2 rows, what should I have to do if I want to select only one row at a time on the basis of id?

Answer (score 1):

Two similar solutions, using **[`APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)** operator:

```
SELECT t.Id,
       MIN(m.Price)
FROM   
    tableX AS t
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT Price = Price1 UNION
      SELECT Price2 UNION
      SELECT Price3 
    ) AS m
GROUP BY t.Id ;



SELECT t.Id,
       x.Price
FROM   
    tableX AS t
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP (1) Price
      FROM 
       ( SELECT Price1 UNION
         SELECT Price2 UNION  
         SELECT Price3
       ) AS m (Price)
       WHERE Price IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY Price ASC
    ) x ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1abeb/19)**

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
Select Id,
       Case When Price1 < Price2 And Price1 < Price3 Then Price1
            When Price2 < Price1 And Price2 < Price3 Then Price2 
            Else Price3
            End As TheMin
From   
    YourTable
```

OR

```
select 
    Id, 
    MIN(Price) TheMin
FROM
(
    select Id, Price1 Price From YourTable
    union all
    select Id, Price2 Price From YourTable
    union all
    select Id, Price3 Price From YourTable
)x group by Id
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I can't use cases, as any of the three columns can be null, so to handle null we again have to make many cases. Thats why I am ignoring this logic

Comment: What should be the result if any of the column value is `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

**Take maximum value for NULL:**

```
Select Id,
       Case When ISNULL(Price1,MaxPrice) < ISNULL(Price2,MaxPrice)  And ISNULL(Price1,MaxPrice)  < ISNULL(Price3,MaxPrice)  Then ISNULL(Price1,MaxPrice)
            When ISNULL(Price2,MaxPrice)  < ISNULL(Price1,MaxPrice)  And ISNULL(Price2,MaxPrice)  < ISNULL(Price3,MaxPrice)  Then ISNULL(Price2,MaxPrice)  
            Else ISNULL(Price3,MaxPrice) 
            End As TheMin
From   
    YourTable
```

When MaxPrice could be calculated or just max int...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this post. My though is that you could invert the table column & row and simply use min() to get the minimum.

[Select MYSQL rows but rows into columns and column into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288014/select-mysql-rows-but-rows-into-columns-and-column-into-rows)

(All credit to Anax in the linked post)