# sql query to get multiple column data as row

Tags: mysql, database, group-concat

I am trying to get multiple column data returned in a single row. 
I have a table like this:

```
NAME TESTCASE DATE       TIME
DC   abc      2014-04-03 0.063
DC   abc      2014-07-17 0.057
DC   def      2014-04-03 0.051
DC   def      2014-07-17 0.078
```

I want to get table output like this:

```
NAME TESTCASE TIME_01 TIME_02 
DC   abc      0.063   0.057   
DC   def      0.051   0.078
```

I tried to use GROUP_CONCAT(TIME), but i could not get data in seperate columns TIME_01 and TIME_02. Also i could not get second row of data.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you may see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288014/select-mysql-rows-but-rows-into-columns-and-column-into-rows

Comment: Thanks Fisherman, this is helpful.

Comment: I am curious, i got multiple comments/Answer from another user (Juergen D) 8 hrs ago, but i am not seeing his comments/Amswer now. I don't know how they got deleted?